# OpenBSD OpenSSL version after update to -stable

Tags: openssl, openbsd

Yesterday I installed OpenBSD 5.5 release and after reading about updating and applying patches to the system (http://www.openbsd.org/errata55.html) I decided to update to the -Stable ("patch branch") following this guide http://www.openbsd.org/stable.html. All went well but when I'm running openssl version i get the following:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

Is this correct? When I´m reading about the patches applied  I was very eager to get the patch ***002: SECURITY FIX: April 8, 2014*** applied to avoid the server being vulnerable to the "Heartbleed-bug".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, openbsd 5.5 uses openssl 1.0.1c. If you applied the patches and recompiled, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also try using openup from [mtier.org](http://www.mtier.org/index.php/solutions/apps/openup/) next time around even though it isn't official